# Is possible to deploy existing app to Docker?

Tags: docker, mean-stack

I have existing MEAN stack application. I found more tutorials, but I cannot find anything about deploying existing app to Docker. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you install your application in Linux or Windows?

Comment: Pretty much -every- tutorial is about stuffing apps into docker.   That's why it exists.

Comment: @user2915097 I'm developed on windows, but I want deploy to ubuntu environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can get the sources of your project on your deployment platform (the Ubuntu server), you can then follow the guide "[Dockerizing a Node.js web app](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/)".
It shows how to create a simple web application in Node.js, then build a Docker image for that application, and lastly run the image as a container.

You can see a [more complete example at Semaphore](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-node-js-web-application).

Comment: Great. Thanks! :)